# Get contact's thumbnail by contact's ID - Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-contacts

I'm trying to get a contact's photo (if it has one) but I've noticed for the contact I selected (and it has a thumbnail) it's not appending the right image, but instead it's displaying a image from another contact - or not adding image at all.
I've checked the ID and its correct but somehow its not displaying the photo I'm looking for?

Does anyone knows how I can fix this issue?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(data.get(position).getContactID()));

            Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

            Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver()
                    .query(
                            photoUri,
                            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO},
                            null, null, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to get the contact photo with contact id

```
private void retrieveContactPhoto() {

        Bitmap photo = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(contactID)));

            if (inputStream != null) {
                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            assert inputStream != null;
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is  Long(contactID))); contactId in this if i define thong then it gives me null